# A question in matrix polynomial norm .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Suppose

- ${\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{A_1}\lambda  + 
  {A_0}$ and ${\rm{Q(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{B}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{B_1}\lambda  + {B_0}$ and ${\rm{Z}}(\lambda ){\rm{ = (}}{{\rm{A}}_m} + {B_m}){\lambda ^m} + .....({A_1} + {B_1})\lambda  + ({A_0} + {B_0})$ are matrix polynomials.
- $\left\| {{A_j}} \right\| = \mathop {\max {{\left\| {{A_j}x} \right\|}_2}}\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} $ and $\left\| {{B_j}} \right\| = \mathop {\max {{\left\| {{B_j}x} \right\|}_2}}\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} $
- $\left\| {P(\lambda )} \right\| = \mathop {\max }\limits_j \left\| {{A_j}} \right\|$ and $\left\| {Q(\lambda )} \right\| = \mathop {\max }\limits_j \left\| {{B_j}} \right\|$
- $\det (P(\lambda )) \ne 0$ and $\det (Z(\lambda )) = 0$ and $\left\| {{B_j}} \right\| \le \varepsilon $.

Is this true that $\left\| {P(\lambda )^{ - 1}Q(\lambda )} \right\| \ge 1$?

Comment: What if all $B_i$'s are zero?

Comment: At least one of them is nonzero

Comment: This now follows (not all $B_i$ are zero) from the recent edit, introducing $Z(\lambda) = P(\lambda) + Q(\lambda)$ and requiring $\det(Z(\lambda)) = 0$ while $\det(P(\lambda)) \neq 0$.  The Question seems poorly motivated, especially with the introduction of a "norm" on the matrix polynomials that departs from the claimed norm on matrices, i.e. $||A||$ appears to be simply the operator norm for Euclidean norm on vectors (while the matrix polynomial "norm" is a maximum over coefficients).

Comment: This notational conflict is especially grave because the ultimate question posed is whether $||P(\lambda)^{-1} Q(\lambda)|| \ge 1$.  How is the latter to be interpreted?  For given $\lambda$, the expression inside the "norm" is a matrix, but is no longer a matrix polynomial.

Comment: Cross-posted to MO: [Simple question on polynomials](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218503/simple-question-on-polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

Of course not, unless there is some relation between $P$ and $Q$ that you forgot to tell us about.

Comment: @ Robert Israel - Thanks